# Why width: 100% is not assuming the full window width size?

Tags: html, css, width, dimension

I have HTML code and CSS below:

```css
body{
 background-color: #C7C7C7;
}
#content{
 background-color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
}
.warp{
 padding:15px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 700px;
 background-color: red;
}
#header{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
 HEADER IS HERE
</div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="warp">
  CONTENT IS HERE
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

But when I resize my browser, a header div not `width: 100%`

You can see that in this image: [image]

How to fix it?

Thanks you so much.

Comment: can you define what you need ? i don't understand your question.

Comment: I want header width :100% but it's not working. You can see in picture. div#Warp > div#Header

Comment: you means in full size it will not in 100% ?

Comment: Yes I want header width is full size of browser windows.

Comment: are you make the responsive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you resize the browser there's a fixed width div i.e. `.wrap` div to 700px and if you resize the browser the window width is upto 700px but 100% width is applied to the view-port width.

So, how you can do is to apply max-width to the `.wrap` div:

```
.warp{
    padding:15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 700px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;/*for padding values*/
    background-color: red;
}
```

So, in smaller window `.wrap` div won't go beyond the 100% view-port width and your header would be in corresponding with that and in larger window the `.wrap` div won't go beyond the 700px as what you want.

---

Here's the demo:

```css
body{
 background-color: #C7C7C7;
}
#content{
 background-color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
}
.warp{
 padding:15px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 700px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: red;
}
#header{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
 HEADER IS HERE
</div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="warp">
  CONTENT IS HERE
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I was add max-width: 100%; but it still not working ?

Answer (score 2):

Hey there is no problem with your header.
Problem is reside in your

```
.warp{
    padding:15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 700px;<-- because of fixed width content go outside the body tag
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `.warp{}` this div you give `width: 700px` fix. So you can use media screen and give `.warp{}` div `width: 100%`. Or give `.warp{}` div width on percentage(%).